# swipe.js Transition End Function

Tags: jquery, html

I've implemented swipe.js by @bradbirdsall (http://swipejs.com/)

The plugin has a transitionEnd feature. How can I get it to direct the user to .index.html when they reach the last slide?

```
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
callback: function(index, elem) {},
transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
});
```

New to jQuery. Happy to learn but short on time here. Thanks in advance for any help!

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this for a similar need

```
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('userSlider'), {
  startSlide: 0,  
  speed: 400,
  continuous: false,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false,
  callback: function(index, elem) {
    if(window.mySwipe.getPos() === 3){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#userSlider').fadeOut();
        }, 500);
      }
     },
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
  });
```

you could also do this, achieves the same result

```
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('userSlider'), {
  startSlide: 0,  
  speed: 400,
  continuous: false,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false,
  callback: function(index, elem) {},
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {
    if(window.mySwipe.getPos() === 3){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#userSlider').fadeOut();
      }, 500);
     }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback and/or transitionEnd, you can use the following [Swipe APIs functions](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/master/README.md#swipe-api) to check if you are at the last slide:

- `getPos()` returns current slide index position
- `getNumSlides()` returns the total amount of slides

Obviously with these informations you can check if you are at the last slide, and redirect your user to `index.html` setting `window.location` in the function accordingly, for example.